# Is there a way to 'movie credits style' scroll down on a webpage with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there a way to 'movie credits style' scroll down on a webpage with pure CSS ? I'm building a wordpress simple website / webpage and looking for this trick but can't find anything anywhere. For simplicity purpose I'm looking for pure CSS solutions and curious if there's any.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
.page-id-39{
  animation: scroll-down 2000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-down {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(100vh); }
}
```

The (WIP!) page that's supposed to auto scroll down https://wagmigeneration.net/wagmi/

Comment: Are you talking about adding a [Parallax effect](https://medium.com/@dailyfire/pure-css-parallax-simple-tricks-da102d0ffdb9)?

Comment: Almost but no need for parallax, just the scroll effect. I'm trying.

Comment: By scroll effect do you mean the credits should gradually go up (not down) like at the end of a movie. Please provide enough code for us to see the problem, though I suspect you are just missing a minus sign.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Just that, the page should go up like at the end of a movie. The website is a wordpress stack, so you can attribute CSS to a given page quiete easily. I'm doing this also for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it works

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    animation: scroll-up 1600s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-up {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}
```